# Unable to run CRON for scheduled jobs in Drupal 7.43 and Civicrm 4.7.7

Tags: civimail, cron, scheduled-job

I have tried running a cron job in drupal 7.43 and civicrm 4.7.7 with no success. I have a scheduled job:
Home » CiviCRM » Administer CiviCRM » Scheduled Jobs (Send Scheduled Mailings) with setting Run frequency   "Every time cron job is run" (BTW the job runs if I use Execute now)(I have also set at 1 hour intervals)
In Drupal;
Home » Administration » Configuration » System > CRON it is set to run every hour and does so. I also can run it from the external URL.
When I run the Drupal CRON it has no effect on the Civicrm scheduled job and Civicrm complains each time I log in to Civicrm;
"Cron Not Running - Last cron run at May 16th, 2016 4:48 PM." which is the last time I executed it manually (Execute now).
I am doing this as administrator with all permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a cron command on the server.

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs

Something like

```
*/15 * * * * wget -O - -q -t 1 'http://mysite.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=username&pass=password&key=site-key'
```

If you have set it, what is the exact cron command for CiviCRM you have set on the server (cpanel, directadmin ....)? (You can leave out the pwd)

Comment: In the Cpanel from my host CRON documentation it gives an example "/home/user/public_html/index.php" . Can I use your example given above instead of this format?
I have used the pass key from civicrm.settings.php located in /sites/default
here is the command line:
*/5 * * * * wget -O - -q -t 1 'http://http://mysite.com/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=ihocking&pass=password&key=abc123d2f72471f0e48336e594f2141a

Comment: Please do no use the info from your civicrm.settings.php. You need to create a user in Drupal (e.g. civicron) and set a password to this user. The user must have enough permissions in CiviCRM to do the scheduled job. Use the name and password form this user for the cron call.